# Error passing multiple parameter to PHP function (Object of class comments could not be converted to string error)

Tags: php, sql

This may be something really simple but I'm still in learning stages of PHP. I made a class that could be used to pass parameters from another page to it. I've tested the function while passing one parameter to it and it works but seems to throw the "Catchable fatal error: Object of class comments could not be converted to string" error.

```
class comments{
 public function insertcomment($postid, $postcomment){
    include('db-conx.php');
    echo "<br/>$postid<br/>";
    echo "$postcomment";
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $date = date('M d,Y h:i:s');
    $insertcomm = "INSERT INTO comments (`userid`,`postid`,`commentdate`,`commentcontent`) VALUES         (?, ?, ?,?)";
    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
    if ($stmt->prepare($insertcomm))
    {

        //$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $userid,$postid,$date,$postcomment);
        echo "$postcomment";
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "True";
    }
    else{
        echo "false";
    }
}
}
```

Call the function and page the other parameter in other page by

```
$postcomment = new comments();
$returned=$postcomment->insertcomment($postid, $postcomment);
```

Been up a day debugging with little luck. Any help?

Comment: Please show us the *entire* error message, including file number. Also, point out where in your code the error occurred (using a single-line comment, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You are usinig the variable $postcomment twice. I assume you have a string in it before you override it with creating a new comments object? Please try:

```
$comment = new comments();
$returned = $comment->insertcomment($postid, $postcomment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay everyone I feel pretty dumb. It turns out I reassigned $postcontent in the code right above calling it. Probably a sign I need more rest since I spent all night battling this.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be passing the object back in to the method by mistake. $postcomment is an instance of comments(), but then you pass $postcomment to insertcomment as a parameter?

Comment: Questions do not belong in answers. Please use the comments section.

Comment: Firstly, at this point I didn't have enough rep to comment. What would you have preferred me to do in that case?